# Count rows where specified values appear in specified columns

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I currently have a worksheet with sample data:

```
   |     A     |     B     |     C     |
---------------------------------------
1  | SHAPE     | SIDES     | COLOUR    |
---------------------------------------
2  | Rectangle | 4         | Blue      |
---------------------------------------
3  | Rectangle | 4         | Orange    |
---------------------------------------
4  | Rectangle | 4         | Red       |
---------------------------------------
5  | Square    | 4         | Blue      |
---------------------------------------
6  | Square    | 4         | Orange    |
---------------------------------------
7  | Square    | 4         | Red       |
---------------------------------------
8  | Triangle  | 3         | Blue      |
---------------------------------------
9  | Triangle  | 3         | Orange    |
---------------------------------------
```

In sheet 2 I am using a formula to count the rows of each colour (by matching the cell value):

```
   |     A     |     B     |
---------------------------
1  | COLOUR    | TOTAL     |
---------------------------
2  | Blue      | 3         |
---------------------------
3  | Orange    | 3         |
---------------------------
4  | Red       | 2         |
---------------------------
```

Formula in Cell B2:

```
=COUNTIF('Sheet 1'!$C$1:$C$1000,A2)
```

Formula in Cell B3:

```
=COUNTIF('Sheet 1'!$C$1:$C$1000,A3)
```

Formula in Cell B4:

```
=COUNTIF('Sheet 1'!$C$1:$C$1000,A4)
```

I would now like to count colour types with specific number of sides (e.g., Orange shapes with four sides). I am getting stuck on how to achieve this.

Comment: Look into [COUNTIFS()](https://exceljet.net/excel-functions/excel-countifs-function).

Comment: `COUNTIFS` is probably what you want.  If you find a solution, please post it as an answer.  If it doesn’t work for you, please [edit] your question (do not respond in comments) to show what you tried, what results you got, ***and an example of what results you want**.*

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if my understanding is correct, please try this formula:

For 4 SIDES: `=COUNTIFS(Sheet1!$C:$C,$A2,Sheet1!$B:$B,"4")`

For 3 SIDES: `=COUNTIFS(Sheet1!$C:$C,$A2,Sheet1!$B:$B,"3")`

[image]